# Read and write output command in LUA

Tags: lua, popen

I'm making a project where i call a service in lua.
In that service, i execute a command. Then i write the output of the command to a file.
Then at least i read the whole file and i take 1 line from it.

Now i started to program it but i have a really weird bug, i think ..

When i execute my command with popen, no output is going to the file. But i see that the command whas executed. When i do a second popen. Then we write the output to the file. But problem there is, i don't want to execute the command 2 times.

So the main problem & question is. How can i fix my code so that the script writes the output to the file and then reads every line. With only one popen.

This is my code :

```
    services.CreateVirtualDesktop = function(me, headers, query, data)  
--  local handle = io.popen("sudo -u pi tightvncserver")
  file = io.open("/home/pi/OutputVncCommand.txt","w")
  handle = io.popen("sudo -u pi tightvncserver")
  output = file:write(handle:read("*all"))
  handle:close()
  io.close(file)

   files = {}
   f = assert(io.open("/home/pi/OutputVncCommand.txt","r"))
  if not f then return files end 
        local k = 1
    for line in f:lines() do
    files[k] = line
    k = k + 1
  end
  f:close()
  return 200,files[8]
end
```

Comment: Try   `os.execute("sudo -u pi tightvncserver > /home/pi/OutputVncCommand.txt")`

Comment: Tried it, but still no output to my file ..

Comment: Just for testing, replace `tightvncserver` with something simple, e.g `echo ABC`

Comment: If i do an echo then he puts the ABC to the file

Comment: if it works with `echo ABC` but doesn't work with `tightvncserver` then something is wrong with running this app (access rights, env vars, etc.).